# IE8 for Ubuntu latest version

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have download the latest desktop version for [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

I want to run internet explorer 8 in ubuntu. I found this instructions

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingInternetExplorer

but they are only for IE6 and previous version. How can I configure IE8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why exactly you would want IE8 in Ubuntu, it's a Microsoft browser written for Windows (and not a very good one at that)

If you just want this for web testing then you can get a VM image for several versions of IE, provided by Microsoft - https://www.modern.ie/en-gb/virtualization-tools#downloads

I realise this doesn't exactly answer your question as it's asked, but I feel like "the" answer is probably not the "right" answer for whatever it is you want.

Comment: This is relevant in case you want to access a legacy device with a webinterface, that require plugins and such.